# Microsoft Edge: How to go round mixed-content error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge, loopback, mixed-content

My Edge version is:

Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

When I do an jQuery http request via

```
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:20101/?action=test');
```

on an intranet page with https, the Edge console says 'SEC7111: [Mixed-Content]' and the request does not arrive.

What I tried:

- Running "CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" as administrator account
- Checked "Allow localhost loopback" under about:flags

The request works with Firefox and IE. I know the potential security risk, but since it is loopback address it should be no problem.

Hopefully someone can help me out here, thanks!

Comment: You can't get round this. It's a security restriction. You need to access the required content over a secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

**Mixed content** occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. Different browsers each behave differently with mixed content. Usually, modern browsers display warnings about this type of content to indicate to the user that this page contains insecure resources.

If there's mixed content, Microsoft Edge will have a prompt [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kceIl.png), you could click the icon marked yellow in the search bar, then a prompt will pop up, click **"See all content"** then the blocked content will show.

If you want to avoid mixed content blocking fundamentally, the best strategy is serving all the content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

*Reference link: [(1) What Is Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

[(2) How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content#How_to_fix_your_website)*